# R: Equivalent command to Matlab's keyboard function?

Tags: r, matlab, debugging

Does **R** provide a similar command for debugging like Matlab's [`keyboard`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/keyboard.html)?

This command provides an interactive shell and can be used in any function.
This gives access to all variables allowing one to verify that the input data is really what it should be (or test why it's not working as expected).

Makes debugging a lot easier (at least in Matlab...).

Comment: I have never debugged anything in Matlab with `keyboard`.

Comment: @OlegKomarov It was recommended by a colleague of mine (but for matlab) - and the workflow seams pretty nice (debugging in Rstudio is not really that nice....)

Comment: @Dennis RStudio is working on many new features in that vein in their [preview](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/download/preview) release of the next version.

Comment: @ Dennis: [Revolutionary R](http://www.revolutionanalytics.com/downloads/) already has menu based debugging as in `Matlab` and `Gauss`.

Comment: keyboard is how I always debugged stuff in MATLAB

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for `browser()`.

From the description:

> A call to ‘browser’ can be included in the body of a function.
>   When reached, this causes a pause in the execution of the current
>   expression and allows access to the R interpreter.

It sounds like you're new to debugging in R so you might want to read [Hadley's wiki page on debugging](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Exceptions-Debugging).

Comment: The link is pretty helpful! Thx

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `?recover`, this function provides great debugging functionality.